# What is the BigO of Swift's String.count?

Tags: arrays, swift, big-o

When swift uses `String.count` is it:

**O(n)** where each time we call it we iterate through the entire String in order to count it

*or*

**O(1)** where swift has previously stored the size of this array and simply accesses it.

Comment: It is `O(n)` for sure. From the [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID297): "be aware that the count property must iterate over the Unicode scalars in the entire string in order to determine the characters for that string". The only question is  whether is a caching mechanism once `count` has been determined and the string has not been modified

Comment: @CodeDifferent Interesting. That paragraph appears to imply that `Array.count` would be `O(1)` if each element takes up an equal amount of space.

Comment: @Deco that paragraph is specifically about `String.count` and not `Array.count`. Even though a `String` is actually a `Array<Character>` in Swift 4, you should never forget that it doesn't always behave like a normal `Array` due to the nature of Unicode grapheme clusters and normal characters. This is especially important for indexing and counting characters in a `String`. See this sentence from the same documentation: _"As a result, the number of characters in a string can’t be calculated without iterating through the string to determine its extended grapheme cluster boundaries."_

Comment: @CodeDifferent Not really. `O(n)` would be the worst performance. Actually `String` has several ways to store data and maintains some helping flags, e.g. `isAscii` that can reduce the complexity to `O(1)`.

Comment: @Sulthan last time I looked, `String` uses either ASCII or UTF-16 internally. Given how many characters exist outside the ASCII table, I'd say assuming `O(n)` is the safer way.

Comment: @Code And `opaque` :) I am trying to find some caching but it seems to me there is no `count` caching. You are right that we should always assume the worst though

Comment: Technically speaking, `O(n)` is an asymptotic *upper bound*, so even if `String` did cache the `count`, it would still be technically correct to describe the time complexity as `O(n)` ;) Also, [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2950091-count) for `Collection` says that the performance of `count` is "*`O(1)` if the collection conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`; otherwise, `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the collection*" – so given that `String` isn't a `RandomAccessCollection`, it's `O(n)`.

Comment: @CodeDifferent I don't think there is a caching mechanism. I mistakenly set n to the number of times I call `count` rather than the length of my `String` in my first answer. Our speed still went down at a rate of N.

Comment: @CodeDifferent This has been answered better in the comments than the answers. Feel free to put your initial comment in as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @Hamish [`RandomAccessCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection) means what exactly? Does it mean types that we can subscript them like `[2]`

Comment: @Honey A `RandomAccessCollection` is a collection whose indices can be offset `n` places in `O(1)` time. Because `count` is a measure of how many times you can offset the `startIndex` to end up at the `endIndex`, random-access collections can always get their counts in constant time. Being a random access collection does not necessarily imply having integer indices though. For example, a `ReversedCollection<[Int]>` is a `RandomAccessCollection` (thanks to conditional conformances), but it has an opaque index type that keeps track of the base collection's index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is definitely `O(n)`. From the [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID297):

> As a result, the number of characters in a string can't be calculated without iterating through the string to determine its extended grapheme cluster boundaries. If you are working with particularly long string values, be aware that the `count` property must iterate over the Unicode scalars in the entire string in order to determine the characters for that string.

This has a few implications, the biggest of which is integer subscripting (i.e. `str[5]`) is not available through the standard library. Internally, `String` uses ASCII or UTF-16 encoding (from Swift 5, it uses [UTF-8 only](https://swift.org/blog/utf8-string/)). If the string only uses ASCII characters then `count` can be `O(1)` but ASCII only has 127 characters so consider this an exception rather than the rule.

`NSString`, on the other hand, always uses UTF-16 so accessing its `length` is `O(1)`. And also keep in mind that `NSString.length != String.count` (try strings with emojis and you'll see).

As for your second question, it does not cache `count` for subsequent calls. Every call to `count` is thus `O(n)`, even if the string has not changed. The code in the [Foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation) repo also confirms that.

Answer (score 1):

After failing to find documentation on this or being able to find this function within the source code I tested this myself using performance tests as described below. It assumed O(1) was possible based on [PHP's Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835241/is-phps-count-function-o1-or-on-for-arrays) being O(1). Swifts `String.count` function appears to be **O(n)**.

**Results**

[image: Unit Test Results]

**Is `count` cached when it's been called before now? (no)**

I also tested to see if calling `String.count` once would cache it. By comparing results when `count` has already been called and when it has been stored to a variable to ensure it's not being stored prior to calling `.count` in our normal tests.

[image: Caching Tests]

**Tests**

```
import XCTest

class CountTests: XCTestCase {

    func test100K() {
        let testString = String(repeating: "a", count: 100000)
        self.measure {
            _ = testString.count
        }
    }

    func test1000K() {
        let testString = String(repeating: "a", count: 1000000)
        self.measure {
            _ = testString.count
        }
    }

    func test10000K() {
        let testString = String(repeating: "a", count: 10000000)
        self.measure {
            _ = testString.count
        }
    }

    func test10000KCached() {
        let testString = String(repeating: "a", count: 10000000)
        _ = testString.count
        self.measure {
            _ = testString.count
        }
    }

    func test10000KStrong() {
        let testString = String(repeating: "a", count: 10000000)
        let count = testString.count
        self.measure {
            _ = count
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These tests don't even mean anything, since you're not changing `testString.count`, simply changing how many times you call `testString.count`... This has nothing to do with the asymptotic time complexity of `String.count`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor You're right thank you. I've updated my answer, would this be accurate? It appears like this is `O(n)`.

Comment: Your updated tests at least do take the size of the input into account, but they're still not really conclusive, since you're only testing plain ASCII Strings. Moreover, as it was established in the comments on the question itself, the documentation does state that `String.count` is `O(n)`, so there's no need for running any tests

Comment: It's not surprising the PHP's String has `O(1)` count and indexing. It uses fixed-length (8 bit) code units, and doesn't support Unicode.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like O(n) to me based on a quick Playground test.

```
for step in 1...10 {
    let length = step * 100000
    let string = String(repeating: "x", count: length)
    let start = Date()
    let stringLength = string.count
    let end = Date()
    print("Length: \(stringLength), time: \(end.timeIntervalSince(start))")
}

// Length: 100000, time: 0.00178205966949463
// Length: 200000, time: 0.00132298469543457
// Length: 300000, time: 0.00184988975524902
// Length: 400000, time: 0.00218689441680908
// Length: 500000, time: 0.00302803516387939
// Length: 600000, time: 0.00368499755859375
// Length: 700000, time: 0.0039069652557373
// Length: 800000, time: 0.00444602966308594
// Length: 900000, time: 0.0052180290222168
// Length: 1000000, time: 0.00539696216583252
```

Comment: Never use the playground to do any kind of performance tests.

Comment: You are not really checking the `count`. You are also checking how long it takes to generate the data. You are checking ASCII strings only anyway which is an error considering the implementation.

Comment: Admittedly quick and dirty, but the string is created before I capture the start time.

Comment: @closetCoder even if your test code wasn't quick and dirty, you should never assess performance in a Playground since there can be huge performance differences between Playground execution or execution on a real device, regardless of which Apple platform you're targeting.

Comment: OK, I'm sure you are right. Here are the results from the same code inside a fully compiled macOS app. Same machine. Same conclusion, I think.

Length: 100000, time: 0.000870943069458008
Length: 200000, time: 0.00115108489990234
Length: 300000, time: 0.00173497200012207
Length: 400000, time: 0.00217998027801514
Length: 500000, time: 0.0027470588684082
Length: 600000, time: 0.00323700904846191
Length: 700000, time: 0.00389111042022705
Length: 800000, time: 0.00445103645324707
Length: 900000, time: 0.00502490997314453
Length: 1000000, time: 0.00524795055389404

Comment: Repeated the test in macOS app using unicode character "" rather than "x". Much slower. Cut the length of the strings to speed it up. Definitely not O(1). Worse than O(n).

Length: 1000, time: 0.0232720375061035
Length: 2000, time: 0.0928299427032471
Length: 3000, time: 0.196869015693665
Length: 4000, time: 0.343490958213806
Length: 5000, time: 0.536596059799194
Length: 6000, time: 0.76084303855896
Length: 7000, time: 1.03708600997925
Length: 8000, time: 1.35282206535339
Length: 9000, time: 1.72617793083191
Length: 10000, time: 2.12419903278351

Comment: _Never use the playground to do any kind of performance tests_ . Why? @rmaddy

Comment: @Honey Because the playground is doing all kinds of work behind the scenes. It's not a fair test.

Comment: @Honey have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052267/4667835) SO answer about measuring code performance in a playground, written by an Engineering Manager at Apple. He clearly explains why the official standpoint is not to do any time measurements in a playground.