# Keep local variable inside a function or not in swift to reduce execution time and memory?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am working on a project, where we are following a proper code guideline. But recently I stumbled upon a problem whose solution is not in my guideline.

The problem is simple. I have two functions one keeping a local variable to store the return value and the other returning the value directly without storing. Here I have added the sample example.

```
class MockClass {
    enum InputEnum {
      case testOne
      case testTwo
      case testThree
    }
    
    enum ResultEnum {
        case resultOne
        case resultTwo
        case resultThree
    }

    func testFunction1(_ param1: InputEnum) -> ResultEnum {
        var resultEnum: ResultEnum
        
        switch param1 {
        case .testOne:   resultEnum = .resultOne
        case .testTwo:   resultEnum = .resultTwo
        case .testThree: resultEnum = .resultThree
        }
        
        return resultEnum
    }
    
    func testFunction2(_ param1: InputEnum) -> ResultEnum {
        switch param1 {
        case .testOne:   return .resultOne
        case .testTwo:   return .resultTwo
        case .testThree: return .resultThree
        }
    }
}

let myClass = MockClass()

let start1 = DispatchTime.now()
myClass.testFunction1(.testThree)
myClass.testFunction1(.testOne)
let end1 = DispatchTime.now()
let nanoTime1 = end1.uptimeNanoseconds - start1.uptimeNanoseconds
print(nanoTime1)

let start2 = DispatchTime.now()
myClass.testFunction2(.testThree)
myClass.testFunction2(.testOne)
let end2 = DispatchTime.now()
let nanoTime2 = end2.uptimeNanoseconds - start2.uptimeNanoseconds

print(nanoTime2)
```

In order to determine, which function guide should I follow, I chose the execution time as a parameter in `Xcode 14.1 playground`. I have added the function execution time calculation code.

Sadly I am unable to determine which function the execution time is less. Because the execution time changes if I change the position of the execution block.

I instinctively followed the `testFunction2` as a guideline. The reason, in `testFunction1` I have an extra assign operation and an instance variable that does not exist in `testFunction2`.

Apart from the assigned operation and making an instance variable, I don't find any extra work in `testFunction1`.

As for memory consumption, I am assuming  `testFunction2` takes less memory since there is no instance variable.

Is my understanding adequate?

Comment: They compile to the same exact binary with `-O`. This is purely a stylistic choice.

Comment: Profile with Xcode/Instruments (in your real app) and check if it makes any difference. Most probably, it does not. Then decide on a version which you find easier to read/understand.

Comment: Note also that the Playground is notoriously slow and not at all suited for performance measurements, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/24030848/1187415.

Comment: @Sweeper You are saying that in the compiled file both functions are the same. But what I understand `testFunction1` is creating a local instance, then assigning the value, and finally returning. In `testFunction2` directly create a local variable then return.

Comment: "But what I understand..." So? What you understand does not affect how the compiler behaves.

Comment: @Sweeper What about the compiler preprocess execution time in both functions? Do both functions take the same time? If not when I use them inside the `Xcode` project, during build time one of the function takes more time right?

Comment: I bet that you will not notice any (significant) difference in a compiled project (with optimizations on), neither in compilation time nor in execution time.

Comment: @MartinR My project is already taking a huge time during the first-time build and incremental build. As I am going to set the standard, everyone will be supposed to follow this. That's why I am also concerned about the compilation time. Anyway, at least I know it won't affect the compiled product.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of premature optimization.

You are talking about a function with a **local** variable vs one that does not have a local variable. Local variables are created on the stack, and only exist during the time the function is executing. Because local variables are stack variables, they do not take any more persistent memory.

The Swift compiler is very sophisticated, and with optimization turned on, it's likely that it will optimize away the local variable and the object code for the 2 versions will be identical.

In any case, any difference in execution time will be so small that it will be hard to detect.

As others have said, playgrounds are very slow-executing, and the slowness of the playground will almost certainly overshadow any performance differences you are trying to measure.

You would need to set up a release build that ran both versions of your function millions of times and measured the time needed for each version.

In situations like this, the time that matters is **developer** time. If you write contorted, highly optimized code that is hard to follow and hard to maintain, but doesn't create speed improvements that are meaningful to the **consumers** of the application, you are wasting developer time, now and in the future. Developers are expensive.